# Sprite class in OpenFL (formerly NME) for empty placeholder objects?

Tags: sprite, game-engine, haxe, nme, openfl

I am experimenting with [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) and [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) and am wondering if the `Sprite` class is synonymous with a `GameObject` in [Unity](http://unity3d.com). It seems that sprite instances have a hierarchical structure and I am wondering if this can be utilised to manage objects.

For example:

```
Game (Sprite / container / no visual representation)
 |--> Grid (Sprite / container / no visual representation)
       |--> Tile (Sprite)
       |--> Tile (Sprite)
       |--> ...
 |--> ...
```

Am I correct with the above assumption, or should the `Sprite` class be extended purely for objects with visual representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need a container, you should extend [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://www.openfl.org/api/types/nme/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html). But for abstract things like `Game`, I wouldn't use a `DisplayObject` at all, but custom classes.

Use classes extending from `DisplayObject` only for things that should be added to the *Display List*. In your example, `Game` shouldn't be a `Sprite`, but `Tile` and `Grid` probably yes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class. The only reason I have **Game** is because that was automatically generated by the tool that I am using, though by default it is named **Main**. I suspect that it would be better to derive that from `DusplayObjectContainer` also. I will experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use that in my project, so probably the answer is 'yes' :)

In particular I use a grid with N horizontal sprites, so my isometric map is rendered in proper top-to-bottom order. I also use a single container for my HUD etc.

There are some caveats to this approach - "invisible" sprites cannot capture mouse events, and they cannot have their width/height set programmatically (only by adding children at appropriate positions).